# `this` value changed in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

[Reproduction in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2vjcch)

I have a component file that looks like below
TS File

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
  myArray: this.fb.array([])
})
constructor(private myService: MyService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}
fullNameMap = (names: any[]) => {
  names.forEach(({firstName, lastName}) => {
    (this.myForm.get('myArray') as FormArray).push(
      this.fb.group({
        firstName: [firstName],
        lastName: [lastName]
      })
    )
  })
}

fullNames$ = this.myService.data$.pipe(
  tap(this.fullNameMap)
)
```

This works but the problem is that If I try the same approach in webstorm it throws an error `TSLint: Declaration of instance field not allowed after declaration of instance method. Instead, this should come at the beginning of the class/interface. (member-ordering)`

If I interchange `fullNames$` and `fullNameMap`, now typescript complains again `TS2729: Property 'fullNameMap' is used before its initialization.`

I finally tried the below code

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
  myArray: this.fb.array([])
})
fullNames$ = this.myService.data$.pipe(
  tap(this.fullNameMap)
)
fullNameMap (names: any[]) {
  names.forEach(({firstName, lastName}) => {
    (this.myForm.get('myArray') as FormArray).push(
      this.fb.group({
        firstName: [firstName],
        lastName: [firstName]
      })
    )
  })
}
```

Typescript error disappears, but now I receive error `cannot get property 'get' of undefined`. The 'this' value in the function `fullNameMap`  inside the class seems to have changed and is no longer the class instance.

Please advise on a workaround this. Currently I am using //@ts-ignore:no-use-before-declare

Comment: In the first snippet you have an initialisation for `myForm`. That seems to be missing in the second one.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is simply a matter of a function losing its `this` context when passed as a callback.

Methods declared with the `methodName() {}` syntax, unlike arrow functions, do not lexically bind `this`.

You need to bind it:

```
fullNames$ = this.myService.data$.pipe(
  tap(this.fullNameMap.bind(this))
)
```

Comment: But not a good approach, you should use arrow function.

Comment: @KamranKhatti Why?

Comment: @JLRishe no need to bind method if you can get value and simply pass to the method, checkout how tap operator works https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap and read more about diff between arrow and normal function online.

Comment: @KamranKhatti Still not sure what you're trying to say. I don't see why `(names) => this.fullNameMap(names)` would be any better than `this.fullNameMap.bind(this)`. The first one just seems like extra noise. I understand just fine the difference between arrow and normal functions, and that documentation on the tap operator doesn't give any indication of why one would be better than the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind` or just use the arrow function.

I modified this demo.

```
...
  fullNames$ = this.myService.data$.pipe(
    tap((names) =>　this.fullNameMap(names))
  )
...
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5cn46h?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem (`TS2729: Property 'fullNameMap' is used before its initialization`) is because that you are using arrow functions which are not `hoisted`.

> Arrow functions mostly behave like function expressions. They are
> expressions rather than statements, which allows them to appear in
> expression position. The brevity of the arrow function syntax is
> extremely helpful for small functions passed to a higher-order
> function

You can read more about differences between function expression and declaration here: https://medium.com/@mandeep1012/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions-b43646042052

The second problem can be solved by using arrow functions or `bind` like this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
fullNames$ = this.myService.data$.pipe(
  tap(this.fullNameMap.bind(this))
)
```

You ecstatically use arrow functions and expressions in wrong places

Answer (score 1):

Thats bcz you are using normal function instead of arrow function (which is now highly recommended. [check out the difference](https://medium.com/better-programming/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256)).

And the usage of [RxJS tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator also recommended the arrow function.

```
fullNames$ = this.myService.data$.pipe(
 tap((names) => this.fullNameMap(names))
)
```